# Non-Identical results from String Identifier and Actual Class names for activations, loss functions, and metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have the following keras model that is working fine:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
     #first convolution
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", 
                         input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3)),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     #second convolution
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu"),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     #third convolution
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     #flatten the results to feed into a DNN
     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
     #only 1 neuron, as its a binary classification problem
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              loss="binary_crossentropy", 
              metrics=["acc"])
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=15,
             steps_per_epoch=100, validation_data = validation_generator,
             validation_steps=50, verbose=1)
```

However, when attempting to replace the magic strings, and use actual class names for activations, loss functions, and metrics, I have the following model, which compiles fine, but accuracy is always 0. This model is behaving differently than the one above, with everything else remaining the same. Here is the new model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
     #first convolution
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
                input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3)),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     #second convolution
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     #third convolution
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     #flatten the results to feed into a DNN
     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
     #only 1 neuron, as its a binary classification problem
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
    ]
)
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=15,
                steps_per_epoch=100, validation_data = validation_generator,
                validation_steps=50, verbose=1)
```

I am guessing I have made a mistake in replacing the magic strings with class names, but I can't spot the mistake. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we set **String Identifier** for accuracy as `['acc']` or `['accuracy']`, the program will choose the relevant metrics for our problem, like whether it's binary or categorical type. But when we set the actual class name, we need to be a bit more specific. So, in your case, you need to change your metrics from

```
tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
```

to

```
tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
```

Read the content of each from [`.Accuracy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy), and [`.BinaryAccuracy()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/BinaryAccuracy)

---

Here is one dummy example to reproduce the issue and solution for a complete reference.

```
# Generate dummy data
np.random.seed(10)
x_train = np.random.random((1000, 20))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))
x_test  = np.random.random((800, 20))
y_test  = np.random.randint(2, size=(800, 1))

# model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile and run
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=10, verbose=2,
          batch_size=128, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

With **String Identifier**, it will run OK. But if you change metrics to `.Accuracy()`, it will give you zero scores for both the train and validation part. To solve it, you need to set `.BinaryAccuracy()`, then things will run as expected.